# How to style ajax data in html

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-core

I have successfully retrieved data from ajax query, however, I a finding it difficult to style it the way I want the data to look like

I am expecting the data to be represented as `<li></li>` tags which is clickable. Below is my code and the expected output.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Message/GetMessages",
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data)
        {
            $('#counter').html(data.length);
            $(data).each(function (index, notice)
            {
                var list = $('#messageList').append('<ul></ul>').find('ul');
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    list.append('<li><h6>' + notice.subject + '</h6><p>' + notice.body + '<br/></p></li>');
                }
                
            });
            
            
            console.log(data);
            },
        
        error: function (xhr, status, error) { }
    });
```

the expected output is the image below

[image]

Comment: can you provide exactly what the API returns?

Comment: @EmreBener this is the raw data
`{"messageId": "04ebfda7-9aff-42d1-8ef7-4794193e4e8f",
    "body": "New Member with Member by name  NSIAH  GLORIA-JWC026 has been created",
    "isRead": 0,
    "sender": "Eklexia",
    "subject": "New Member",
    "reciever": "SuperAdmin",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "createdDate": "2023-10-17T19:38:12.7848068",
    "modifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "createdBy": "",
    "modifiedBy": ""
}
`

Comment: you need to use javascript to perform DOM manipulation and dynamically fill the contents of the notification container, and you also need to have adequate CSS knowledge to be able to position the box properly in the page. I assume there is no web sockets in place? users only see their notifications when they click the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My test result:

[image]

My controller:

```
public List<Message> message() {
    List<Message> mes = new List<Message> { 
        new Message{
            messageId = "04ebfda7-9aff-42d1-8ef7-4794193e4e8f",
            body = "New Member with Member by name  NSIAH  GLORIA-JWC026 has been created",
            isRead = 0,
            sender="Eklexia",
            subject="New Member",
            reciever="SuperAdmin",
            isDeleted=false
        },
        new Message
        {
            messageId = "asdf",
            body = "ddddddd",
            isRead = 1,
            sender="user1",
            subject="delete Member",
            reciever="Admin",
            isDeleted=true
        }
    };
    return mes;
}
```

My View:

```
<button id="showList">show message</button>
<div>
    <div>message list</div>
    <a href="/home" style="text-decoration:none; color:black;">asdf</a>
    <ul id="mesgList">
        <li>
            <a href="/home">
                <div class="itmHead" style="overflow:hidden" >
                    <div style="float:left;width:150px;" >comment</div>
                    <div style="float:left;width:150px;text-align: right;"> yesterday</div>
                </div>
                <div class="subject">
                    subject
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    content
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#showList").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/home/message",
                type:"get",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) { 
                    console.info(data);
                    var html = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
                        var item = '<li>'
                                    + '<a href="/home" style="text-decoration:none; color:black;">'
                                        + '<div class="itmHead" style="overflow:hidden" >'
                                            + '<div style="float:left;width:150px;" >comment</div>'
                                            + '<div style="float:left;width:150px;text-align: right;"> yesterday</div>'
                                        + '</div>'
                                        + '<div class="subject">'
                                            + data[i].subject
                                        + '</div>'
                                        + '<div class="content">'
                                            + data[i].body
                                        + '</div>'
                                    + '</a>'
                                + '</li>';
                        html += item;
                    }
                    console.info(html);
                    $("#mesgList").append(html);
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. Your input was very helpful